# Does it make sense to create a database user for each system admin at my company, or should we share a database account?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mongodb

Should I be creating a Mongo user for each physical developer that needs access to MongoDB, or should we just share a "sysadmin" account?

There's three of us that need full access, and everyone needs the same permissions. We only have a few thousand users and don't have any special compliance requirements (not healthcare, finance, etc.). Everyone on my team I deem trustworthy and competent. We all have sudo access, and there are no other Linux accounts on the server (besides apache, etc.).

I'm considering this since it's a lot more work to set up multiple users and there is negligible benefit. (If a team member left, I'd just change the password). However, if there is a real reason to create separate users (if it helps post-breach auditing/investigations, etc.), I'd be more than happy to do so.

If we shared I would create a simple bash script to "wrap" the mongo commands, like this, and add it to a group only given to us three developers:

```
#!/bin/bash

/path/to/bin/mongo -u="username" -p="password" $@
```

This would prevent the password from ever leaving the server in the first place.

---

I was originally considering the security implications of writing a script like the one above that has a unique password for each user and having the file owned by them with `700` permissions. The assumption would be that keeping the password "hidden" from the user would be safer than having it on their clipboard/stored on their local computer in some random `password.txt` file on their desktop.

But, I started thinking: there's no reason to have three separate accounts if the three of us could just `sudo cat` to see the other password anyway.

I think making each user keep a password locally with a password manager is overkill as, since they already have sudo, it's easy enough to just disable authentication in the Mongo config file in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

A shared account means it's harder (r impossible without proper system/access logging) to determine who actually logged if something goes wrong.

Also if one of those people is terminated/quits, you can't remove ONLY their access, you'd have to change the password for the shared account, as you said.

If people are really storing passwords in clear text on their systems, that a whole other security can of worms to address.

I'm not sure why you think 3 separate accounts is considered a significant amount of work, as you probably spent more time writing this question.

Comment: `If people are really storing passwords in clear text on their systems, that a whole other security can of worms to address.` We use a password manager with randomly generated passwords for all of our production API accounts. However, after talking with my team more, they say a password manager specifically for MongoDB is a pain as we each authenticate at least half a dozen times a day. One of the other developers claims we're too small of a target to worry about a MongoDB password being stolen from a disk, and if someone had local access to steal such a password, they could easily install...

Comment: ...a keylogger/copy our private keys and gain access to the server directly. I think storing the password with 700 permissions on the same server that runs the database is low risk as an attacker who could read a 700 file and use that password would already have to have root access (and it takes three minutes to disable authentication with MongoDB if you have root access). I'd personally prefer the password manager, but I respect the other developer's wishes to not lose productivity to protect against such a rare scenario, and I think keeping it on the server is a fair compromise. Am I wrong?